# How to convert responseText value to an integer?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a php script that compute the difference between two dates.

```
<?php
  $date1="2015-11-30 07:57:00";
  $date2=date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

  $diff=abs(strtotime($date2)-strtotime($date1)); 
  echo "<h1 style=\"color:red;\">".$diff."</h1>";
?>
```

Then I thought to use an ajax request to auto refresh every second.

```
function loadXMLDoc(){
     var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
     xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
         if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
             var totalsec=xmlhttp.responseText;
             document.getElementById("ajaxDiv").innerHTML = totalsec;
         }
     }  
     xmlhttp.open("GET","dif_btw_dates.php",true);
     xmlhttp.send();
}
setInterval("loadXMLDoc()",1000);
```

Now I would like to compute the *totalsec* value to determinate the number of minutes, hours and days. But when I tried to make any math operation over *totalsec*, like

```
var minutes=totalsec /60;
```

I get a NaN error. How to convert the responseText value to an integer so I can made math operations? Thanks.

Comment: try `parseInt()` or `Number()`

Comment: And when the server takes longer than a second to return?? Hello log jam of Ajax requests piling up and coming back in the wrong order. You need to either abort the previous request if it is open or think about another solution.

Comment: What is the value of `totalsec`?

Comment: You need to re-think here, you shouldn't make an ajax call every second to display a time diff. Do a client side calc and then like every minute, or every 10 minutes, or even only every hour, and if you really need to, you make a server request to sync. If you don't do like this, you will load your server with way more work than necessary.

Comment: Ramanlfc I've tryed those functions and didn't work. Hamlet Hakobyan at the moment the variable have 133250 of value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem here is that you are trying to parse `<h1 style="color:red;">123123</h1>` into a number. Also, as pointed out by [@LGSon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2827823/lgson), you shouldn't make an ajax call every second here.

To resolve this I would send back the two dates from the server instead, it could look something like this:

PHP:

```
<?php
  $date1="2015-11-30 07:57:00";
  $date2=date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
  echo $date1 . "," . $date2;
?>
```

HTML:

```
<div id="ajaxDiv">
  <h1></h1>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#ajaxDiv > h1{
  color: red;
}
```

and the JS:

```
var date,
    timezoneOffset;

function loadXMLDoc(){
     var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
     xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
         if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
             var dates = xmlhttp.responseText.split(",");
             timezoneOffset = Math.round((new Date() - new Date(dates[1]))/3600000);
             date = new Date(dates[0]);
         }
     }  
     xmlhttp.open("GET","dif_btw_dates.php",true);
     xmlhttp.send();
}

function updateTime(){
    if( date === undefined ) return;
    var date2 = new Date();
    date2.setHours(date2.getHours() - timezoneOffset);
    var totalsec = (date2 - date) / 1000;

    /* Here totalsec is a number and you can do your other operations like 
       var minutes=totalsec /60; */

    var ajaxDiv = document.getElementById("ajaxDiv");
    var h1 = ajaxDiv.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0];  
    h1.innerHTML = totalsec;

}

loadXMLDoc();
setInterval(loadXMLDoc, 3600000); //Sync with server time once an hour
setInterval(updateTime, 1000);
```

Comment: Thanks. Now I understood where was the problem and you give me a clear suggestion to improve the code.

Answer (score 0):

```
var sec = parseInt(xmlhttp.responseText);
```

Comment: @João Then your problem is server side, in your php.

Comment: What is the error? The cause might be that xmlhttp.responseText is not a number.

Comment: It's a Apache 2.4 version localhost server with PHP 5.6.15 version.

Comment: That is the error in JS? Add try/catch block and see the error.