# How can I extract number value from responseText property?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm having trouble with simple Ajax / JavaScript / PHP. I am using Ajax to call a PHP script that generates a random number.

I have managed successfully to call a script and to show that random number inside a  element.

But the problem is, I need to use that number for later calculations and I don't know how to convert `xhttp.responseText` to number and store it in a var.

All i get from `.responseText` is either `Nan`, either `undefined`, or in this case `<p id = "number">VALUE</p>`.

Can anyone help, please?

Here is the full code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <button id= "btn" type="button" onclick="loadDoc()">Generate number</button>
    <div id="random">
        <p id = "number"></p>
    </div>
    <script src = "javascript.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

function loadDoc() {
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("number").innerHTML =
            xhttp.responseText;
        }
    };
    xhttp.open("POST", "script.php", true);
    xhttp.send();
    console.log(number);
}

//PHP

<?php
    function getRandom(){
        $rand = rand(1,16);
        return $rand;
    }
    echo getRandom();
?>
```

Comment: have you viewed this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34029809/how-to-convert-responsetext-value-to-an-integer  Also you are not returning anything from php. Add echo before getRandom() function

Answer (score 1):

Change your php code to

```
<?php
function getRandom(){
    $rand = rand(1,16);
    return $rand;
}
echo getRandom();
?>
```

you are not returning anything from php. Add echo before getRandom() function

```
//New Edit
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
</head>
<body>
<button id= "btn" type="button" onclick="loadDoc()">Generate number</button>
<div id="random">
    <p id = "number"></p>
    <input type='hidden' id="number_1" value='0' />
</div>
<script src = "javascript.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

<script>
    function loadDoc() {
      var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
          document.getElementById("number").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
          document.getElementById('number_1').value = xhttp.responseText; //This sets the value in hidden field and you can use it later.
          alert(document.getElementById('number_1').value);
        }
      };
      xhttp.open("POST", "script.php", true);
      xhttp.send();
      console.log(number);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Yes, sorry, I did this but I forgot to include it in code. Still can't extract any numeric value from it

Comment: The random value gets append in the p tag with id number. Do you want to get the value of p tag like we do for text boxes etc. Check my edited answer

Answer (score 1):

to parse number from string, use js function parseInt(). and probably check your php returning anything